# Inserting shapefile Data without Duplication into PostgreSQL database shapefile table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I am using QGIS.

I have a database (PostgreSQL) with tables having geometries. I have been trying to merge/add data existing in a shapefile format to that table without duplication to no sucess.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you have some unique attribute in the shapefile that can be used for joining the two data sets?

Comment: You can create a constraint that check unicity of geometries for example.